# CSS <li> height difference in Google Chrome

Tags: css

Please Check the attached image

```
ul li{ 
    width:100px;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    border:10px double #333;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
}

<ul>
    <li><a href="image.jpg"><img src="image.jpg"/></a></li>
</ul>
```

[image: attached image]

Comment: what is the height of the image? 200px, right?

Comment: Try to check out the Chrome Dev Tools: it should help you to figure out whats rendered it a different way than in Firefox.

Comment: we need more details, use jsfiddle please

Comment: I tested your code in chrome and it works fine. Your image is likely inheriting padding or margins from a specific style. In chrome, right click/cmd click your problem area and select 'Inspect Element' from the list that appears. You can use this to determine the source of the problem pretty quickly.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VfryQ/

That problem doesn't exist with the code you provided... the only property i added was "overflow: hidden" to the image because the image i used stretched outside the li element. you must have other styles applied that it's inheriting.

Comment: I replicated your problem, hope it helps..

http://jsfiddle.net/VfryQ/1/

Do you have any styles applied to img elements?

Comment: have you added the reset css. if not then try this. 
body, ul { padding:0 !important; margin:0 !important; }
a, img {display:block;}

Answer (score 1):

I find the best way to reduce these inconsistencies is to use a CSS reset (a quick Google search will bring many results). What this does it pretty much set everything to 0 within your stylesheet.

From there, everything you define in your styles is how you want it to be displayed. It of course isn't 100% perfect, but it does a good job of getting you on your way.

[1 of many CSS resets out there](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: I do know CSS, but why, what makes you say that, they are widely used by many people? By saying "learn CSS" makes you sound idiotic, they do what they do, rather than having to specify on all my styles as `margin: 0` over and over etc why not just declare it at the top and then only specify if it alters from 0. To me that seems more logical and cleaner.

Comment: Used by people who don't know CSS well, or who think that CSS is FUBAR without a reset.

Comment: Apparently including, for instance, [Eric Meyer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_Meyer), [Paul Irish](http://paulirish.com/), the [YUI team](http://www.yahooapis.com/yui/reset/)...

Comment: Yes but I do know CSS well, I've written many stylesheets without a reset, but I find it just makes my life so much easier, declaring a load of global properties. Why make things harder for yourself?

Comment: That's different, they created it. They KNOW css. They didn't just run into a small fixable problem and go "oh dear, GOOGLE -> RESET CSS" So I guess more appropriately, I should have said, "Using a reset css that you didn't write is for noobs"

Comment: I found the solution it's     ul {list-style: none;}

Comment: Ah. Well, if your comment was "make sure you know CSS, and then carefully consider whether resetting your CSS would make life easier", then I think we're probably agreed. But I don't see that I should have to write my own reset; I'd probably miss something. So long as I understand what the reset author was doing when he did it, I'm golden.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have to write `display:bloc`k or `vertical-align:top;` in your `IMG` tag.

for example

```
img{display:block}
```